# Show an image as Tooltip in a Unity 3D

Tags: unity, image, unity-ui, image-effects

I got the following question:

How to show an image as Tooltip in a Unity3D?
The image should only be visible if the user hovers over the 3d object.

Thanks in advance,

hidayah

Comment: Your recent edit changed your question from a conceptual question to a "debug my code" question. That's a completely different question. Please post it as a new question. When you do that, please don't forget what "error" you have. Which means to tell your readers which line generates the error and the exact wording of the error message.

Comment: ...which, as I just found out, [you already did 2 days ago](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/205696/display-image-by-using-tooltip). Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I will do it better next time.

Answer (score 1):

First we need to find out what object the mouse cursor is pointing at. You can do that by combining `Input.mousePosition` with `camera.ScreenPointToRay` and `Physics.Raycast`. Keep in mind that the object needs a collider for raycast hits to register. [Here is an example from the official manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CameraRays.html).

Now that we got the position and the object, we need to visualize the tooltip itself. I recommend to do that with a fullscreen [UI canvas](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UICanvas.html) with a single panel that contains whatever you currently want to show. You can control the panel's position by getting its [`RectTransform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html) component and setting its position to the `Input.mousePosition`.

Comment: Remember you'll need to convert Input.mousePosition which is in screen space into the coordinate space of the UI canvas. [RectTransformUtility. has a helper method to make this easy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html).